# Combining dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine the following dictionaries into the ideal output and am not sure how it is done.

```
day1 = {'Sci': [21.0],'Math': [16.0]}
day2 = {'Sci': [11.1],'Math': [16.1]}
```

Expected output:

```
{'Sci': [21.0, 11.1],'Math': [16.0, 16.1]}
```

How can I go about it?

Comment: your expected output doesn't combine them really. Also the numbers in your expected output change. What have you tried so far?

Comment: We don’t know either what the rule for this particular input and output should be. It’s not obvious.

Comment: Shouldnt the output be something like: `{'Sci':[11.0, 11.1], 'Math':[16.0, 16.1]}` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I made some edits to the question.

Comment: @user21138479: Are you *guaranteed* every `dict` will have the same set of keys, and values in the form of a `list` of `float`s? If even one of them might be missing a key (or equivalentl, if one might have an extra key), `collections.defaultdict(list)` is probably what you want to build on.

Comment: And are the (shared) keys guaranteed to be in the same order? Examples should reflect the aspects of the real data, so right now you're making it look like your dicts always have the same keys in the same order

Comment: Can it be assumed they have the same keys each with a single corresponding value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```py
day1 = {'Sci': [21.0],'Math': [16.0]}
day2 = {'Sci': [11.1],'Math': [16.1]}

output = {key: d1 + d2 for (key, d1), d2 in zip(day1.items(), day2.values())}

print(output)
```

Output:

```py
{'Sci': [21.0, 11.1], 'Math': [16.0, 16.1]}
```

Assuming `day1` has the same keys as `day2`.

Edit: if we are going to assume that, the previous method is way overcomplicated. This suffises:

```py
output = {k: day1[k] + day2[k] for k in day1}
```

Comment: Actually the simpler solution also has the advantage of working if the keys appear in the dicts in different order.

Comment: @KellyBundy KISS working in my favour haha

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, here is my attempt at solving your problem. Please keep in mind this only works if both of your dictionaries have the same keys.

```
day1 = {'Sci': [21.0],'Math': [16.0]}
day2 = {'Sci': [11.1],'Math': [16.1]}

output = {}
for key in day1:
    output[key] = day1[key] + day2[key]

print(output)
```

The code above will give you the following output:

```
{'Sci': [21.0, 11.1], 'Math': [16.0, 16.1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, I like to create a generic function to simplify the task at hand.

Here is a helper function which accepts any number of input `dict` objects to merge the K/V pairs of:

> Note: this assumes that all values in an input `dict` object are of type `list`.

```py
def merge(*dicts):
    res = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for k in d:
            if cur_list := res.get(k):
                cur_list += d[k]
            else:
                cur_list = d[k]
            res[k] = cur_list
    return res
```

Now, calling the function via:

```
day1 = {'Sci': [21.0],'Math': [16.0]}
day2 = {'Sci': [11.1],'Math': [16.1]}

print(merge(day1, day2))
```

Result:

```
{'Sci': [21.0, 11.1], 'Math': [16.0, 16.1]}
```